# Cannot get subview to be inserted into layout

Tags: marionette

I am creating a webapp using Marionette.Backbone and I got a module that creates a layout and add three subviews to it.

The layout is rendered fine but the regions are not filled with each sub view.
What am I missing. I get no error in the console.

**This is my controller:**

```
@Appic.module "ProjectsApp.Add", (Add, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    Add.Controller =

        addProject: ->
            @layout = @getLayoutView()

            @layout.on "show", =>
                @showLeft
                @showContent
                @showRight

            App.mainRegion.show @layout

        showLeft: ->
            leftView = @getLeftView
            @layout.leftRegion.show leftView

        showContent: ->
            contentView = @getContentView
            @layout.contentRegion.show contentView

        showRight: ->
            rightView = @getRightView
            @layout.rightRegion.show rightView

        getLeftView: ->
            new Add.Left

        getContentView: ->
            new Add.Form

        getRightView: ->
            new Add.Right

        getLayoutView: ->
            new Add.Layout
```

**This is my view part of the module**

```
@Appic.module "ProjectsApp.Add", (Add, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    class Add.Layout extends App.Views.Layout
        template: "projects/add/templates/add_layout"

        regions:
            leftRegion: "#left-region"
            contentRegion: "#content-region"
            rightRegion: "#right-region"

    class Add.Left extends App.Views.ItemView
        template: "projects/add/templates/_left"

    class Add.Right extends App.Views.ItemView
        template: "projects/add/templates/_right"

    class Add.Form extends App.Views.ItemView
        template: "projects/add/templates/_form"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a pointer to the function rather than the functions result in your show methods.  Try:

```
    showLeft: ->
        leftView = @getLeftView()
        @layout.leftRegion.show leftView

    showContent: ->
        contentView = @getContentView()
        @layout.contentRegion.show contentView

    showRight: ->
        rightView = @getRightView()
        @layout.rightRegion.show rightView
```